# htacess how to convert two query strings to one url

Tags: php, mysql, apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

```
  Options +FollowSymlinks
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
  RewriteRule ^news/([^/]+)  /casino2/newsdetail.php?newsid=$1 [NC]
```

Currenty using the above code to conver `http://localhost/casino2/newsdetail.php?newsid=3` to
`http://localhost/casino2/news/3`   now what problem is i am trying to make  one url out of two query strings like if url is `localhost/casino2/newsdetail.php?newsid=3` & `pagename=article`    the url should be  `localhost/casino2/news/article` is it possible to do so ?

Comment: Didn't you mean `localhost/casino2/newsdetail.php?newsid=3&pagename=article`?

Comment: yes like its localhost/casino2/newsdetail.php?newsid=3&pagename=article  i want to make it localhost/casino2/news/article

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To start with, those rules appear to do the opposite of what you say you want - i.e. they're rewriting "/localhost/casino2/news/4711" to "/casino2/newsdetail.php?newsid=4711".

Provided this is what you really mean, what you need to do is to save two items into two variables, instead of just one into one variable, like this:

```
RewriteRule ^news/([^/]+)/([^/]+)  /casino2/newsdetail.php?newsid=$1&pagename=$2 [NC]
```

If the newsid is always 1, so that you don't need to pass it to the php, you simply create it in your replacement, like this

```
RewriteRule ^news/([^/]+)  /casino2/newsdetail.php?newsid=1&pagename=$1 [NC]
```

This would create the following rewrites:

/news/article -> /casino2/newsdetail.php?newsid=1&pagename=article
/news/somethingelse -> /casino2/newsdetail.php?newsid=1&pagename=article

But if you want to be able to select different newsids, you need to pass it in somewhere - either as part of the URL or as a querystring.

Just to be clear, the way the rules are applied is

```
RewriteRule "What the URL looks like in the browser" "What my web server expects"
```

If you have problems, I highly suggest you turn on a lot of debug logging, it'll be a great help. The relevant config lines are

```
RewriteLog /path/to/logfile
RewriteLogLevel 3
```

Comment: Thanks a lot but  i want the url to be written like this 
news/(what ever pagename equals)   with url to be re written  is  /casino/newsdetail.php?newsid=1&pagename=anypagename

Comment: I think you got confused about the order the rewrite is applied. I hope I managed to clarify it and you can make it work.

Comment: THanks a lot Jenny but still i think youre not getting my point i know its my fault i couldnt  really manage to explain it  any how
             RwriteRule  "I want url to be like this h**p://www.casino.com/news/pagename"   "What my server will be expecting is h**p://www.casino.com/?newsid=2&page=pagename"

Comment: Then the first rule I posted should be what you want, with some adjustment for your own file structure.

Comment: Rule # works great  But it will work like this it will create a url like this  h**p//localhost/casino/news/2/pagename but i want to show it like this  h**p://localhost/casino/pagename only from two query strings to one .. THanks a lot jenny for helping me along

Comment: Now I'm afraid I don't understand what you mean again. Could you give a couple of more examples?

Comment: this is url my browser will get              
h**p://localhost/news/newsid=1&pagename=anyname 
this is what i want to show to user
h**p://localhost/news/anyname
I hope you getit this way

Comment: OK, got it! New rule coming up :-)